# magento attribute frontend property per product

Tags: php, magento

I need to set a attribute property, like "Used in Product Listing", per product, not globally, for all the products. 
Is there a way to implement this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Get attribute collection ...

```
$attributes = Mage::getModel('eav/config')
    ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
    ->getAttributeCollection()
    ->addSetInfo();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute->getData('used_in_product_listing') == 1)
    {
        echo "{$attribute->getFrontendLabel()}:\n";


        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: No, thats not i'm lookink for. This is just how to show the attribute in frontend. I need to be able to set this attribute per product. Lets say, we have 2 attributes: attr1, attr2. I want the product A to have only attr1 visible in listing, product B to have only attr2 visible in listing, product C to have both attributes visible in listing, ....